# Pseudo-image from CSV data set with xy and measurement in R

Tags: r, image, csv

I'm working off a CSV of over a million rows of data taken from a rectangular sample. The CSV contains 3 columns, x coordinate (in steps of .06 or .07), y coordinate (in steps of .16 or .17) and the reading at that point. I'm looking for someway to visualize the sample in R to create a pseudo-image of the sample based in the readings using a color gradient.

Searching online, this solution seemed promising, [Creating a matrix by color in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299643/creating-a-matrix-by-color-in-r), but I'm running into issues creating a matrix from my data

```
x = c(unique(CTLI$xcoord)) #getting all of the different x values
y = c(unique(CTLI$ycoord)) #getting all the y values
matVar = matrix(CTLI$CTLI, nrow = x, ncol = y)
```

And am getting the error

```
    Warning message:
In matrix(CTLI$CTLI, nrow = x, ncol = y) :
  data length exceeds size of matrix
```

I'm not committed to this solution though, so any other ideas would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the answer you linked too, learning some from it and get there:

```
CTLI <- read.table(text="xcoord,ycoord,measure
12,15,30
16,20,25
19,35,38",header=TRUE,sep=",")

mCTLI <- melt(CTLI,id.vars=c("xcoord","ycoord"))
iCTLI <- ggplot(mCTLI,aes(x=xcoord,y=ycoord,fill=value)) + geom_raster()
iCTLI
```

[image: Resulting]

You don't have to build a matrix before, `melt` create a data.frame suitable for `ggplot`.

Comment: That fixed that problem. Thank you!